# Does Spring-kafka has inbuilt mechanism to restart the kafka stream when the stream transitions into an ERROR state?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We are using spring-kafka for our Kafka Streams application. We currently have a kafkaStreamCustomizer written that listens to stream state transition changes and when it goes into ERROR state, we go tear down the springboot application and restart it. Doing so, we often end up losing some data. With Spring-Kafka, are we even supposed to handle the stream state ERROR? If yes, what will be the best way to handle it gracefully without loss of data?

Spring-Kafka ver: 2.6
Springboot ver: 2.4.9

```
public class KSCustomizer implements KafkaStreamsCustomizer
{
    private AppConfig config;

    AppHealthIndicator healthIndicator;

    HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

    static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;


    public KSCustomizer(AppConfig config, 
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context, AppHealthIndicator healthIndicator)
    {
        this.config = config;
        KSCustomizer.context = context
        this.healthIndicator = healthIndicator;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams)
    {

        kafkaStreams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
            // update app-state metrics triggered by state change
            metrics.update(processMethod, Application.STATE_CHANGES, 1);
            healthIndicator.setCurrent(newState);

            if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.PENDING_SHUTDOWN)
            {
                log.info("Kafka is shutting down");
            }

            if (newState == KafkaStreams.State.ERROR)
            {
                log.warn("KStream entered into Error state.");
                if (config.getRestart().isEnabled())
                {
                    long delay = config.getRestart().getDelay();
                    // calculate delay
                    // long delay = (long) (attempted * (Math.pow(multiplier, attempted - 1))) *
                    // factor;
                    try
                    {
                        log.warn("Error State; about to restart application in {} seconds", delay);

                        Thread.sleep(delay * 1000);
                        restart();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        log.error("Interrupted Exception", e);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    context.close();
                    kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
                }
            }

            if (oldState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING)
            {
                log.warn("Kafka stream process transitioned from {} to {}", oldState, newState);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void restart() throws InterruptedException {
        log.info("About to restart Application ...");
        ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try
            {
                context.close();
                context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.error("Failure in Restarting application: ", e);
            }
        });

        thread.setDaemon(false);
        thread.start();
        log.info("Restarted Application ...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hava you tried to set a uncaughtExceptionHandler for your KafkaStreams? Use the method setUncaughtExceptionHandler from the class KafkaStreams. Method reference from docs: https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-

Comment: Yes, can I assume that if we have an UncaughtExceptionHandler we don't  have to handle the kafka stream state transitions? What if the Stream enters an ERROR state due to connection failure, will spring-kafka handles the restoration by itself?
I'm a bit confused on how to structure UncaughtExceptionHandler to handle the failures in such a way that streams would auto recover on errors & no data is lost. Examples would really help. Thanks

Comment: Spring for Apache Kafka is not involved with the runtime aspects of the stream; it only provides spring friendly configuration mechanisms and a mechanism to manage the overall Lifecycle of the streams. You are on your own for any runtime considerations. You can stop and start the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` programmatically to restart the stream.

Comment: Does stopping & starting StreamsBuilderFactoryBean restart the underlying kafka stream? Could you share any reference documentation that would guide us in right path for handling stream errors & graceful recovery without loss of data & if possible without restarting the entire spring application?